# How to add buttons in python?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I have a code which manages my file transfers. Now I want to add a tkinter to it so I can actually make a button 'run' which will let me run the code. I don't know where to implement the tkinter code as I don't know where to begin.

This is my current code:

```
import os    

source1 = r'D:FolderX'
location2 = 'c:\data\AM\Desktop\destination'

black_list = ['folder1', 'folder2'] 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source1):
    #Exclude the blacklist folders.
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in black_list]
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)  
        if os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:   
            continue                          
        if file.endswith(".tdms"):
            tdms_path = (os.path.join(root, file)) 
            file_size = os.path.getsize(tdms_path)
            
            if file_size == 0:
                 continue
        else:                    
            continue             
        metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
        print(metadata)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys()))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel(locatie2 + '\\' + 'final_sheet.xlsx'
```

Comment: Maybe this article from Geeks for Geeks is useful for you; [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-creating-a-button-in-tkinter/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-creating-a-button-in-tkinter/).

Comment: The first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial. As written, this question is far too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to use buttons with tkinter that I think will help.

```
import tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = tkinter.Tk()

def buttonPressed():
   # put code for what happens when button pressed here
   messagebox.showinfo("Window Title", "The code is now running")

B = tkinter.Button(top, text="Press Me", command=buttonPressed)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!